# Search through a Postgres array with an array

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I'd like to add hashtags to a feature and I'd like to simply store them as an array for each object, then I'd let users search through the items with their own tags (an array of tags) and then perform the search. Is there a good way to do this?

for example:
the tags in the database:

```
row 1: ['red', 'blue', green']
row 2: ['orange', 'blue']
row 3: ['blue', 'green']
```

and then the users search would be something like:

```
['red', 'green']
```

and the results would be row 1 and 3.

is this a really slow and inefficient way to store these? How would I get the best performance if I were giving users multiple options to search for in this manner?

Comment: That's my bad! haha, i'll fix that!

Comment: For performance optimization, you need to provide more information, starting with your Postgres version, table definition, cardinalities, min, max, avg of: array length, attribute length,  number of attributes in search, number of queries. Read / write patterns? It all depends ... Follow instructions in the [tag info for \[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

1. **Use Postgres arrays as you suggested.** This makes your rows simple to read and is fairly straightforward. It also allows you to have an ordering to your tags if needed without storing an index separately. If you go this route, you should use the [&& operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-array.html) to determine whether or not the search tags overlap with other tags (as opposed to running the query in a loop, for example).
2. **Use a separate table for storing object-tag associations**. In such a table, one column is the `tag` (or tag_id if you want to modify tag metadata later) and another is the `object_id` associated with the tag. You can have multiple tags associated with the same object, and multiple objects associated with the same tag. Then, you can use a standard `join` on this table with an [in filter](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/) to get all object IDs that match your requested tags. This is the approach generally used by database management systems that don't support arrays.

Comment: So sorry I took so long to accept this! But I just got this part of the program finally written out and this first part worked greatly! Thank you so much!